# Ошибка при подключении библиотеки

Tags: maven, scala

Проблема такая, есть очень простой Trait:

```
trait Logging {
  private[this] val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  // Info
  def info(msg: String, args: Any*) = logger.info(msg, args)

  def info(msg: String) = logger.info(msg)

  // ... И так далее
}
```

Небольшой тестик в самом проекте:

```
object LoggingTest extends App with Logging {
  info("Info")
  warn("Warn")
  debug("Debug")
  error("Error")
}
```

без проблем запускается и работает.

Но когда я его заливаю в репозиторий и подключаю уже в другом проекте, получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method ua/account/AccountServiceServer$.ua$uraty$logging$scala$Logging$_setter_$ua$uraty$logging$scala$Logging$$logger_$eq(Lorg/slf4j/Logger;)V is abstract
    at ua.account.AccountServiceServer$.ua$uraty$logging$scala$Logging$_setter_$ua$uraty$logging$scala$Logging$$logger_$eq(AccountServiceServer.scala)
```

Либку собираю с помощью maven:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.12.2</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Подключаю так:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
resolvers += "wagon.git" at "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/Uraty/mvn/raw/releases/"
val logging = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "ua.uraty.utils" % "logging-scala" % "1.0"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке вам следует создать object-companion. В тесте вы его создаете и поэтому это работает.